# Guidewire Submission with multiple slices

Tags: guidewire

just curious to know why Submission transaction will have eff dated entities with multiple slices. Any link to Guidewire documentation will be helpful.

Tried various scenarios in lower environments by changing effective date on Submission and quoting multiple times but still it is not reproducible. But we have one incident where it happened so looking for inputs.

Answer (score 5):

Being able to inject future slices at submission is a supported feature of PC and is commonly used in Workers Compensation and GL lines of business along with other commercial use cases.  It's rarely used in personal lines however it can be leveraged as appropriate.  The only oddity it causes is that the ootb PC UI may show an "out of sequence" warning but that typically doesn't cause issues.  Rating will behave normally, iterating across the slices and producing appropriate cost objects for the various slices.

To create this scenario the addition of effdated values needs to be applied to a sliced entity.  The "default" slice date for a Submission is the PeriodStart but that can be manipulated.  For example, the scratchpad code below will add a future-dated vehicle to an existing submission.

```
uses gw.api.util.DateUtil

print("Hello World")
var job = Job.finder.findJobByJobNumber("0000034961")
var pp = job.SelectedVersion
print("All slice dates before edit: " + pp.AllEffectiveDates.join(", ") )

gw.transaction.Transaction.runWithNewBundle(\ b -> {
  if( job.isOpenForEdit(pp)) {
    pp = b.add(pp) as PolicyPeriod
    pp = pp.getSlice(DateUtil.currentDate().addDays(30))  //<<this sets the future date
    var veh = new PersonalVehicle(pp)  //<< this creates a new vehicle in the future date context
    veh.LicenseState = State.TC_CA
    veh.GarageLocation = pp.PolicyLocations.first()
    pp.PersonalAutoLine.addAndNumberVehicle(veh)
  }

}, "su")

var sliceDates = pp.AllEffectiveDates
print("All slice dates after edit: " + job.SelectedVersion.AllEffectiveDates.join(", ") )
```

The effdated api behavior is documented in the Application Guide under the Policy Revisioning topic as linked below.

https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/pc/202310/app/app/pc/topics/c_bu2556048.html

Comment: I should add that any autosplittable effdated entity will also produce a future slice data in a submission if it's changed after doing a "getSlice(date)" operation on the entity.  You are effectively saying, "give me a version of this entity as of date x so I can change it from date x to end of term."

Comment: thank you, let me debug further based on this inputs. I will reach out if there are any questions.

Answer (score 0):

PolicyCenter is not going to do that OOTB, so if you see this on prod and it was not coded specifically to do that, then it's most likely a custom code defect. It will be hard to reproduce. I would look for manually committed bundles, as these tend to result in data inconsistencies. Btw, when was the last time you ran DBCCs? They may uncover more cases like that and help you pinpoint the time it got introduced.

The other option is that someone actually tried to implement this. I have seen this as a requirement few times, where customers would like to add a coverable to the policy at submission time, but not for the full term, think caravans that get used for 3 months a year only, etc. It can be done in Gosu by manually adding effdated objects to the graph with manipulated dates.<strike>, but support for this is rather weak if any.</strike> (I stand corrected by Martin that it is a supported Gosu API behaviour).

Comment: thank you for sharing your inputs. I will reach out if there are any more questions.